# Dockerfile's COPY command does not work normally

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a script, copying it to a container and trying to run.
However, it seems that the COPY command does not work properly.

Below is the contents of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM busybox:latest
COPY random.sh /bin/random.sh
ENTRYPOINT /bin/random.sh
```

And below is the contents of the script file to be copied.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "exit" SIGINT
mkdir /var/htdocs

SET=$(seq 0 999999)

for i in $SET

do
        echo "Running $RANDOM" > /var/htdocs/index.html
        sleep 10
done
```

And in the directory where the Dockerfile belongs, the script to be copied exists as follows.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pp pp   76 Oct  4 09:19 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pp pp  154 Oct  4 09:33 random.sh*
```

Upload the image to Dockerhub by running the following command in the directory where the Dockerfile is located.

```
docker build -t dockerhubid/repo .
docker push dockerhubid/repo
```

And start the container by using the command below.

```
docker start dockerhubid/repo
```

However, the container does not start with the error below. Why can't I find the copied script?

```
/bin/bash: line 1: /bin/random.sh: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with Docker's `COPY` command, but rather the script interpreter shebang at the start of your script. The error is not claiming `/bin/random.sh` does not exist, but that it cannot find the script interpreter `/bin/bash`.

The Busybox image does *not* have a `/bin/bash` interpreter, only `/bin/sh`. You either need to install a Bash interpreter if your script is only bash compatible, or change the first line shebang to `#!/bin/sh`. From a cursory glance, I would think this sample script is `/bin/sh` compatible.

Another important note when building against Windows hosts is that oftentimes the file uses `CRLF` (i.e. `\r\n`) line endings, which is not compatible with Linux shebangs (e.g. it will resolve to `/bin/sh\r`). File endings need to be set correctly to `LF` (i.e. `\n`) for the script to run.

Comment: `$RANDOM` is a bash extension.

Comment: @DavidMaze Tested the following command on the `busybox` Docker image: `docker run busybox sh -c "echo $RANDOM \$RANDOM"` and it seems to produce a random value. I am not sure if this is equivalent to Bash, though. The second `\$RANDOM` is in case the first `$RANDOM` is interpolated by the shell you are executing the Docker command from.

Comment: ...it looks like [BusyBox has configurable support for `$RANDOM`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c#n85), but it's [not required in a POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03).